# UPDATE statement not working for certain columns in SQL Sever

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, case, operator-keyword

I had an update statment in a stored proc. which was not updating any records. Hence I broke the update statement into two parts as mentioned below -

the first update runs successfully but the second update is not updating any tax_id record with the same join condition and matches. I am not sure if the issue is with IN operator usage in the CASE statement or whatnot. Can anybody help?

```
UPDATE s
    SET s.is_updated = '1'
        ,s.update_dt = GETDATE()
        ,s.update_source = 'ECM'
        ,s.party_type = 
        CASE 
        WHEN e.ClassificationType is not null THEN e.ClassificationType
        ELSE s.party_type
        END
    FROM staging_cust_acct s 
        right join MTB_AML.dbo.tb_party_kyc e 
        on s.party_key = e.CustomerInternalID





UPDATE s
SET      s.is_updated = '1'
    ,s.update_dt = GETDATE()
    ,s.update_source = 'ECM'
    ,s.tax_id = 
    case 
    when s.party_type IN ('Individual-Retail','Individual-High Net Worth') then e.TaxIndividualID
    when s.party_type IN ('Corp-Publicly Traded','FI-MSB'
                        ,'Corp-NFP/NGO','Corp-Personal/Non-Operating (WHV)'
                        ,'Corp-Not Publicly Traded/Operating') 
         then e.TaxEntitiesID
    when s.party_type = 'Government' then null
    else s.tax_id end
FROM staging_cust_acct s 
    right join MTB_AML.dbo.tb_party_kyc e 
    on s.party_key = e.CustomerInternalID
```

Comment: The first guess is that the `in` conditions are failing, perhaps due to type sensitivity on the collations, misspellings, or hidden characters in the strings.

Comment: Really update statement with NOLOCK :S

Comment: It's a bit odd to see a RIGHT JOIN used to update the table on the left side. It's not clear (to me) why that's not a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: I'm always suspicious of people who use `RIGHT JOIN`, is this wrong of me?

Comment: RIGHT JOIN is for anarchists and lunatics.

Comment: It's not only a bit odd. How can you update the outer joined table? That makes no sense.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I found the issue. It was the right join. Can you please explain why the query worked on converting right join to left?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - Hi Thorsten. I am a newbie at SQL but I would like to know what you mean. The table I am updating is STAGING_CUST_ACCT which is on LEFT side of join. Outer joined table is tb_party_kyc, right? Please correct me if I am wrong. Why is everybody blaming me for using a RIGHT join? Even if it is a RIGHT join, it should update the STAGING_CUST_TABLE for matches, right? 

I finally got my query working by converting the right join into a left join (see my below answer). However, I am still not sure if my logic behind the below answer is correct or not.

Comment: *FROM a LEFT JOIN b* means "give me all a records even for those where you don't find a matching b". (In the results you will see a records where all b fields are null.) *FROM a RIGHT JOIN b* means give me all b records even for those where you don't find a matching a. (In the results you will see b records where all a fields are null.) You used the latter which means there where pseudo a records, but it was table a you wanted to update, which made no sense, because you can only update what actually exists.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thank you so much! The above explanation was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to update the table on LEFT side of the join using the RIGHT join. Converting the join to LEFT OUTER JOIN worked fine. Moral of the story - Never use RIGHT join :)

```
UPDATE s
SET      s.is_updated = '1'
    ,s.update_dt = GETDATE()
    ,s.update_source = 'ECM'
    ,s.tax_id = 
    case 
    when s.party_type IN ('Individual-Retail','Individual-High Net Worth') then e.TaxIndividualID
    when s.party_type IN ('Corp-Publicly Traded','FI-MSB'
                        ,'Corp-NFP/NGO','Corp-Personal/Non-Operating (WHV)'
                        ,'Corp-Not Publicly Traded/Operating') 
         then e.TaxEntitiesID
    when s.party_type = 'Government' then null
    else s.tax_id end
FROM staging_cust_acct s 
    left outer join MTB_AML.dbo.tb_party_kyc e 
    on s.party_key = e.CustomerInternalID
```

Comment: Okay, let's check if this is what you want. 1. You want to update *all* s records. 2. If you don't find a matching e record for an s record then you want s.tax_id to be set to *null*. 3. e.CustomerInternalID is a *unique* key, so you will *never* get two or more matches for one e. If *all* these statements are true, then your update statement is correct.